# How do I make my Rails api index action show only the instances from a certain id, when I have a nested route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails api with a nested route that should show only the locations of vehicles with a specific id from the endpoint `/vehicles/:vehicle_id/locations` however that endpoint give me all locations of all vehicles. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Here is my code.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :vehicles do
    resources :locations
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_07_27_224818) do

  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "lat"
    t.float "lng"
    t.datetime "at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "vehicle_id"
  end

  create_table "vehicles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "unique_id"
  end

end
```

controllers/vehicles_controller.rb

```
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
   skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    @vehicles = Vehicle.all
    render json: @vehicles
  end

  def create
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new(vehicle_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vehicle.save
        format.html 
      else
        format.html 
      end
    end

  end

  def destroy
    @vehicle.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  private

    def vehicle_params
      # swap id column value with unique_id to avoid conflict with primary key
      params[:vehicle][:unique_id] = params[:vehicle].delete(:id)
      params.require(:vehicle).permit(:unique_id)
    end
end
```

locations_controller.rb

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    @locations = Location.all.order("vehicle_id")
    render json: @locations
  end

  def create
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find_by!(unique_id: params[:vehicle_id])
    @location = @vehicle.locations.new(location_params)    

    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        format.html 
      else
        format.html 
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:lat, :lng, :at, :vehicle_id)
    end
end
```

models/vehicle.rb

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations
end
```

models/locations.rb

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the index method of LocationsController, you are fetching all locations instead of locations for the given vehicle only.

Change LocationsController index method as below,

```
def index
  @locations = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id]).locations
  render json: @locations
end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. That's giving me an error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LocationsController#index
Couldn't find Vehicle with 'id'=eddc57bf-845e-4854-86d9-8d3788fb33c5
`

Comment: Can you tell me how you are calling this page? You must pass vehicle id to achieve this.

Comment: `vehicles/4d316e4b-8542-40b6-9409-bfd0769a115d/locations`. In my params hash in the vehicles controller i swap out `id` for `unique_id` because the api receives requests from an external server with `id` in the body. i swapped them because it conflicted with the default rails `id` column.

Comment: Then you can find vehicle as Vehicle.find_by!(unique_id: params[:vehicle_id]), But make sure this uniqe_id should not be unique across all vehicles.

Comment: Thanks again. What do you mean it should not be unique across all vehicles? Each vehicle has its own unique_id.

Comment: I mean you should have validates_uniqueness_of :unique_id validation in your vehicle model.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Rails api with a nested route that should show only the locations of vehicles with a specific id from the endpoint /vehicles/:vehicle_id/locations however that endpoint give me all locations of all vehicles. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

The index action of your lications controller is showing all locations because that is exactly what you've written it to do:

```
def index 
  @locations = Location.all.order("vehicle_id") 
  render json: @locations 
end
```

Why would expect it to do something other than what you've written?

Instead, try:

```
def index 
  @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
  @locations = @vehicle.locations
  render json: @locations 
end
```

Or just:

```
def index 
  @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
  render json: @vehicle.locations 
end
```

Comment: Both these solutions give me: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LocationsController#index
Couldn't find Vehicle with 'id'=4d316e4b-8542-40b6-9409-bfd0769a115d` when I try and reach `vehicles/4d316e4b-8542-40b6-9409-bfd0769a115d/locations`